# Does there exist a constant curvature curve on paraboloid surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I'm learning differential geometry,and need help with the following question:

Does there exist a constant curvature curve on paraboloid surface $ z = x^2 + y^2$ different from plane curve, i.e $z$ does not constant?

Comment: Regarding "i.e.": Of course there are plane curves other than those contained in the horizontal planes $\{z = z_0\}$ (though I expect in this case none of the others have constant curvature).

Comment: yep, I expect in this case too

Answer (score 1):

Look at a constant-$z>0$ circle.  It has both constant geodesic curvature on the paraboloid, and constant curvature as space curve.

Comment: Good. My only suggestion would be to say "any" rather than "the" in the first sentence.

Comment: Sorry about that, I mean it different from the constant z-circle.